# Power Shell Regular Expression Replace - Cannot concatenate number

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a simple regular expression that I want to use in order to inject a variable value into an XML file.

For this I combine $1 with another variable.

When the variable value is a string I have no problem, but when the value is a number the `$1` replacement of regular expression does not work.

Simplified example:

This works just fine:

```
$val = "YYY"
"Replace the XXX with number" -replace "(the )XXX", "`$1$($val)"
```

Output is: Replace the **YYY** with number

This does not:

```
$val = "123"
"Replace the XXX with number" -replace "(the )XXX", "`$1$($val)"
```

Output is: Replace **$1123** with number

Comment: Replace with `"\`${1}$($val)"`

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm. Both in the example I gave and in the more complicated regex I actually use